# how do i fix filtered words discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

i tried to blur the bad words like n word and other nsfw words, but it doesn't work for some reason. i mean the bot is online but its not deleting the bad words.
here is the code:

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions, is_owner
import json

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/')
status=discord.Status.idle

@client.command()
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason=None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"{member} was banned by {ctx.author.name} for reason {reason}")
    
@client.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member,reason=None):
  await member.kick(reason=reason)
  await ctx.send(f"{member} was kicked by {ctx.author.name} for reason {reason}")

@client.command(aliases=['m'])
async def mute(ctx,member : discord.Member):
  muted_role = ctx.guild.get_role(905765835791036477)

  await member.add_roles(muted_role)
  
  await ctx.send(member.mention + "has been muted")

filtered_words = ["*Can't not say the words here*"]

@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
  for word in filtered_words:
    if word in msg.content:
      await msg.delete
      await client.process_commands(msg)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
 print('we have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

my_secret = os.environ['Token']

client.run(my_secret)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function. You're running

```py
await msg.delete
```

When you should've ran

```py
await msg.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
await message.delete()
```

This is a function
Cheers
Lance :-)